# Error: variable is not a CFArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am trying to create custom UITableViewCells, following this [article](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells).  I add outlets for three fields in the cell.  I am taking data stored in an NSMutableArray and placing them in the custom cell labels.  When debugging, I can see the data in the source array elements, but this is in the cell labels: "variable is not a CFArray".  Obviously it's not working... here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"--> cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"siteTableCell";

    SiteListingsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SiteListingsCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.staLabel.text = [self.staLabels objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    cell.descLabel.text = [self.descLabels objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.dateLabel.text = [self.dateLabels objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

This is the definition of the labels:

```
@interface SiteListingsCell : UITableViewCell  {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *staLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *descLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;

@end
```

This is the definition of sArray:

```
@interface sArray : NSObject  {  //  class (struct) to hold site information

}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *sSiteID;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *sInitialSTA;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *sElev;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *sJobDesc;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *sJobDate;

@end
```

UPDATE: This code gets called when I want to fill sArray and move the values to the custom cell labels:

```
- (void) displaySites {

    NSLog(@"displaySites");

    //  get list of sites and place them in sArray
    slSQLite *dbCode = [[slSQLite alloc] init];
    [dbCode getListOfSites];

    //  put site data into array for display
    NSLog(@"\n2-The array listOfSites contains %d items", dbCode.listOfSites.count);
 //   sArray *sa = [[sArray alloc] init];  // initialize sArray object

    for(int i = 0; i <dbCode.listOfSites.count; i++)  {
        sArray *sa = [dbCode.listOfSites objectAtIndex:i];  //  get the sArray out of listOfSites

        staLabels =  sa.sSiteID;
        descLabels = sa.sJobDesc;
        dateLabels = sa.sJobDate;
    }
    return;
}
```

How do I fix this so it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
staLabels.text =  sa.sSiteID;
```

ect...

Comment: Modified Q to show def of sArray... yes, I'm trying to put data from sArray into labels and display them in a custom cell.  I have data in sArray, but nothing in staLabels, etc.